# Fabricjs - Preview Video in FabricJs via loadFromJSON

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, html5-video, fabricjs

I am trying to load video on Fabricjs canvas using loadFromJSON. First I am adding video to JSON then loading that JSON to same canvas to make it play again. (this is not the end goal but for sake of question so you guys can reproduce the problem) But unfortunately even after trying most of the possible solutions I am not able to do that.

I followed this guide

https://itnext.io/video-element-serialization-and-deserialization-of-canvas-fc5dbf47666d

to make it work as it was given in another stackoverflow answer but looks like it's outdated.
I am getting this error

[image: fabricjs error]

below I am attaching my code. Please have a look.

HTML Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/Bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="c" width="1280" height="720"></canvas>

        <!--Javascripts-->
        <script src="vendors/jQuery/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
        <script src="vendors/Bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="vendors/Bootstrap/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="vendors/FabricJs/fabric.js"></script>
        <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Javascript code from script.js

```
window.cancelRequestAnimFrame = (function() {
    return  window.cancelAnimationFrame ||
            window.webkitCancelRequestAnimationFrame ||
            window.mozCancelRequestAnimationFrame ||
            window.oCancelRequestAnimationFrame ||
            window.msCancelRequestAnimationFrame ||
            clearTimeout
})();
var data = "";
function getVideoElement(url) {
    var videoE = document.createElement('video');
    videoE.width = 530;
    videoE.height = 298;
    videoE.muted = true;
    videoE.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
    var source = document.createElement('source');
    source.src = url;
    source.type = 'video/mp4';
    videoE.appendChild(source);
    return videoE;
}
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var url_mp4 = 'https://player.vimeo.com/external/197634410.sd.mp4?s=0d1deba61e621a45218d6488e384219dc7173ae5&profile_id=164';

var videoE = getVideoElement(url_mp4);
var fab_video = new fabric.Image(videoE, {left: 0, top: 0});
fab_video.set('video_src', url_mp4);
canvas.add(fab_video);
fab_video.getElement().play();

var render_request;
var render = function render() {
    canvas.renderAll();
    render_request = fabric.util.requestAnimFrame(render);
    fab_video.getElement().onended = function() {
        cancelRequestAnimFrame(render_request);
        alert("finished");
        data = canvas.toJSON();
        console.log(data);
        canvas = canvas.loadFromJSON(JSON.stringify(data), canvasLoaded, function(o, object) {
            fabric.log(o, object);
        });

    };
}
fabric.util.requestAnimFrame(render);

function canvasLoaded() {
    canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas);
    var objs = data['objects'];
    for (var i = 0; i < objs.length; i++) {
        if (objs[i].hasOwnProperty('video_src')) {
            var videoE = getVideoElement(objs[i]['video_src']);
            var fab_video = new fabric.Image(videoE, {left: objs[i]['left'], top: objs[i]['top']});
            canvas.add(fab_video);
            fab_video.getElement().play();
            fabric.util.requestAnimFrame(function render() {
                canvas.renderAll();
                fabric.util.requestAnimFrame(render);
            });
        }
    }
}

fabric.Object.prototype.toObject = (function(toObject) {
    return function(propertiesToInclude) {
        propertiesToInclude = (propertiesToInclude || []).concat(
                ['video_src']
                );
        return toObject.apply(this, [propertiesToInclude]);
    };
})(fabric.Object.prototype.toObject);
```

If anyone can say what I am doing wrong It would be great help because I am stuck with this from somedays.

Comment: Try adding `width`/`height` to fabric Image object `var fab_video = new fabric.Image(videoE, {left: 0, top: 0, width: 530, height: 298});`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it got fixed for you or not. But the same issue happened to me when I followed the guide:

https://itnext.io/video-element-serialization-and-deserialization-of-canvas-fc5dbf47666d

I think the issue happens because we are trying to load a video as a image which has a src of '', which leads to the above error(when it tries to read the property naturalWidth). In my case simply upgrading to a later version of fabric fixed the issue.